# Flatten two lists to be in String .csv style Format

Tags: java, flat-file

I have two lists a `List<String> headers` and a `List<Row> rows` which is essentially a `List<List<String>>`
I'm trying to flatten these lists to get this desired output:

```
Name,ID,Value
John Doe,1111,XXX
Jane Doe,2222,YYY
```

I'm currently using in iterator to go over the headers list and appending them to a String builder as so

```
        List<String> headers = ((RowListResult) result).getHeaders();
        List<RowListResult.Row> rows = ((RowListResult) result).getRows();

        output = output.concat(String.join(",", headers)).concat("\n");
        for(RowListResult.Row row: rows) output = output.concat(String.join(",", row.getColumns().toString()).concat("\n")).replace("/[[]]/", "");

        System.out.println(output);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I was going to do the same thing for the rows, however I feel like I am making this way harder then I should be and at the end I'd have to remove the commas at the end of each row. Is there a better way to accomplish this? A nudge in the right direction would be helpful. I can also share anything else you may need just leave a comment.

Data: [image: Data in Debugger]

```
Name,ID,Value
[John Doe, 1111, XXX]
[Jane Doe, 2222, YYY]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.join()`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> headers = Arrays.asList("header1","header2","header3");

    List<String> row1 = Arrays.asList("cell1","cell2","cell3");
    List<String> row2 = Arrays.asList("cell1","cell2","cell3");
    List<List<String>> rows = Arrays.asList(row1, row2);

    System.out.println(toString(headers, rows));
  }

  private static String toString(List<String> headers, List<List<String>> rows) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append(String.join(", ", headers)).append("\n");
    for (List<String> row: rows) str.append(String.join(", ", row)).append("\n");
    return str.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I need a regex to get rid of  [ ] in my final str I will edit question with what output looks like now and code. Then I will award you the answer!

Comment: @C2H50H - You do not need regex to get rid of `[]`; you can use `String::replace` for it.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> header = List.of("Name", "ID", "Value");
        List<List<String>> values = List.of(List.of("John Doe", "1111", "XXX"), List.of("Jane Doe", "2222", "YYY"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.join(",", header).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
        for (List<String> valueList : values) {
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator()).append(String.join(",", valueList).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
        }

        // Display
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name,ID,Value
John Doe,1111,XXX
Jane Doe,2222,YYY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams and then join using a Collector.

```
class Row {
    final List<String> values;
}

class Header {
    final List<String> headers;
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Header header = new Header(Arrays.asList("Name", "Number", "Description"));
    List<Row> row = Arrays.asList(new Row(Arrays.asList("John Doe", "111", "XXX")), new Row(Arrays.asList("John Doe", "112", "XXX")));

    String headerString = header.headers.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    System.out.println(headerString);

    List<String> listOfValues  = row.stream()
        .map(x -> x.values)
        .map(y -> y.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(listOfValues);
}
```

Output:

```
Name,Number,Description
John Doe,111,XXX
John Doe,112,XXX
```

Comment: I still want the headers on it as well

Comment: Needs to be an object I can send downstream

Comment: Adding a final List<String> that will contain the values.